# Getting values of text field which are in associative array form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have below text fields with names as associative array. How can i get value of these fields in javascript and pass it in jquery.

```
<input id="personNameAlt" name="call[1][name]" value="" type="text" class="field">
<input id="personNameAlt" name="call[1][email]" value="" type="text" class="field">


<input id="personNameAlt" name="call[2][name]" value="" type="text" class="field">
<input id="personNameAlt" name="call[2][email]" value="" type="text" class="field">

<input id="personNameAlt" name="call[3][name]" value="" type="text" class="field">
<input id="personNameAlt" name="call[3][email]" value="" type="text" class="field">
```

Comment: Please be aware that JS has objects, not associative arrays. Also you cannot have duplicate IDs. Please remove them.

Comment: Yes, i understand about ids should be unique. How can i access values of these text fields using text field name ?

Comment: @farazch Are the input fields wrapped into a <form>-Tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old way from Netscape, who is the inventor of Javascript, is still valid:

```
document.forms[0].elements["call[1][name]"].value
```

What you need, you just have to wrap your input fields into a form tag.